# PowerShell: How do I append a prefix to all files in a directory?

Tags: powershell, rename, batch-rename, wildcards, bulk

Currently I'm using cmdlets like:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "-","_"}
```

But now I need to add a prefix to the filename for all files in the directory.
I can't predict how long each filename is (it varies), so I can't just use a bunch of `.` wildcards.

I need it to append a fixed phrase to the beginning of each filename, regardless what that filename is.

Comment: See solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874916/5518385

Comment: What is it now? A prefix or a suffix? For a prefix you already got a name so (literally) just add to your prefix or (for a suffix) just add the suffix to it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An alternative approach to a regular expression would be to use simple string operations to create the new file name.

```
$items=Get-ChildItem;
$items | Rename-Item -NewName { "Prefix_" + $_.Name };
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but it seems to go mad and keep trying to prefix filenames over and over until it crashes from the filename being too long -  e.g. running the command above results in filenames like `Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_Prefix_...`

Comment: Split the command. `$items = Get-ChildItem;` And replace the `Get-ChildItem` in the above case with `$items`.

Comment: In the end based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37279979/1557472), I just added ```-Exclude Prefix_*``` to the `Get-ChildItem` command.

Comment: Make it into a one liner without the variables:

    ``Get-ChildItem C:\Directory\Path -File | Rename-Item -NewName { "PrefixName_" + $_.Name }``

Answer (score 14):

You are quite near.

- `-replace` uses RegEX and in a Regular Expression you anchor at the beginning with a `^`
- for a suffix you can similarly replace the anchor at line end with `$`
- to avoid any possible re-iteration of the renamed file enclose the first element of the pipeline in parentheses.

---

```
(Get-ChildItem -File) | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "^","Prefix_"}
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't cause an infinite loop and I don't need to write the prefix twice - like what happens in other solutions with the `-Exclude Prefix_*` to avoid the loop.

Answer (score 2):

To remove prefix of all in folder:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Folderpath\KB*' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'KB*','' }
```

To Add a prefix to all in folder:

```
foreach($item in 'Folderpath')
{
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\ilike\OneDrive\Desktop\All in one script\Single Patch here' | Rename-Item -NewName { "KB" + $_.Name }
}
```

Took a while, hope this can help others in need

Answer (score 0):

get-childitem *.FileExtension_ | foreach { rename-item $_ $*.Name.Replace($*.Name,"Prefix_" + $_.Name) }

Replace FileExtension_ with the extension corresponding to the filetype you want to add prefix to. Or just remove .FileExtension_ along with the "." to add prefix to all files in working directory. Replace Prefix_ with the desired prefix.